# Запросы на пайтоне. requests, POST запрос

Tags: python, requests, steam

[ Album ]
Пытаюсь сделать POST запрос на сайт Steam.com.

Значит, как пишет книжка, пишем r = requests.post(url, data) , url - сама ссылка на запрос, data - словарь с данными если нужно

Нам нужно данные : Логин, пароль и двухфакторный код(Steam Guard)

Значит, куда вводить логин пароль смотрим следующим образом (скрин 1)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как же с Steam Guard ??? В нём нету параметра name (скрин2)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запрос подается один и тот же. Что нажимая на кнопку "Войти" после ввода логина\пароля, что после кнопки "Подтвердить"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А зачем вам параметр name?

- С открытым отладчиком выполните авторизацию.
- После чего перейдите в отладчике на вкладку Network
- Найдите нужный вам запрос (вам поможет фильтрация по xhr)
- Пробуйте подделать такой запрос с помощью Python/requests

Стоит отметить, что вас вероятнее всего будут ждать куки сессии и всякие другие защиты от ботов.

Изучите [примеры кода](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) `requests.Session()`, он будет сохранять передаваемые сервером куки и отправлять их обратно. Это должно здорово облегчить вам жизнь.

А еще лучше - используйте официальный API, если таковой имеется. Вам не придется каждый раз по крупицам разбираться в работе сервиса, вы будите иметь нормальную документацию, поддержку и вас не будут блокировать

Comment: Когда не успешный вход - запросы остаются, если успешный вход - все запросы очищаются. Как быть?

API steam может только следующие:
Доступны веб-API Steam
ISteamNews : Steam предоставляет методы для получения новостных лент для каждой игры Steam.

ISteamUserStats : Steam предоставляет методы для извлечения общей статистики по игре.

ISteamUser : Steam предоставляет вызовы API для предоставления информации о пользователях Steam.

Для авторизации - нету.

Comment: Запросы очищаются потому что вы переходите на другую страницу. В таком случае отладчик браузера вам не очень подходит. Воспользуйтесь BurpSuite. Он фиксирует весь трафик с сайта. Оч мощная вещь. Потратите пару часов на изучение, зато будите иметь универсальный инструмент в запасе. Вам будет достаточно Community Version

Comment: В chrome можно включить опцию `preserve log` и тогда при переходе между страницами журнал вызовов не очищается.